# Will Ubuntu 14.04 work on Asus M5a97 r2.0?

Tags: 14.04

I know it will work, but what problems will I encounter? What drivers should I download? And how do I install this from an external optical drive?

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

If you doubt, why not try the Live CD or USB of Ubuntu to see if you or the laptop likes it.

Comment: Good recommendation! If you use Live CD or USB, you can find that it is OK with your system and if not, what does it need.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problems running Ubuntu on your Asus. I don't see any limitations that would prevent it from running on your computer. Now when it comes to drivers that is a whole different story, for the most part Ubuntu should be able to find generic drivers for your computer; one of the great things about Ubuntu is that everything just works! However some drivers such as a graphics card driver for example may require you to download and install the official driver to get full performance out of the graphics card, mostly due to the fact that the generic driver may not have been designed to take full performance of the capable hardware (At least this was/is my situation). Other than the little tweaks you will have to make, and the few bumps in the road you may come crossed, switching to Ubuntu for the most part should be a smooth transition.